# C# to Capture Body of Outlook Email

Tags: c#, outlook-2007

EDIT #2----
It compiles fine, but I get a debug error of: 
The URL property on the ExchangeService must be set on this line
On This Line of Code
'FindItemsResults findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(128));'
End EDIT #2 ----

EDIT ---
Ugh -- I didn't realize I needed 10 rep points to post an image...let me give a few of the errors.

`1) Type or namespace 'FindItemsResults' could not be found

2) Type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found

3) The name 'service' does not exist in the current context

4) Type or namespace 'ItemView' could not be found`

EDIT ----

I saw the post here -- [How to get email body, receipt, sender and CC info using EWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669794/how-to-get-email-body-receipt-sender-and-cc-info-using-ews) and was looking at this code sampling

```
public class MailItem
{
    public string From;
    public string[] Recipients;
    public string Subject;
    public string Body;
}

public MailItem[] GetUnreadMailFromInbox()
{
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(128));
    ServiceResponseCollection<GetItemResponse> items =
        service.BindToItems(findResults.Select(item => item.Id), new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients));
    return items.Select(item =>
    {
        return new MailItem()
        {
            From = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddress)item.Item[EmailMessageSchema.From]).Address,
            Recipients = ((Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddressCollection)item.Item[EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients]).Select(recipient => recipient.Address).ToArray(),
            Subject = item.Item.Subject,
            Body = item.Item.Body.ToString(),
        };
    }).ToArray();
}
```

But am getting multiple compile errors.  How is a very clear instructions way to read the body of an email using C#?

Comment: post your errors, no one here can read minds so without that info we cannot help you.

Comment: A few error's added to original post.  Sorry, I did not realize that it took 10 rep points to post an image.  I thought that was with my original post.

Comment: I think it should be `FindItems` not `findItems`

Comment: It is set as FindItems in the code.

Comment: This code snippet is not complete for connecting to EWS.  service is probably an instance of ExchangeService.  A good getting started article is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220499(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: @Jesse thank you for that link.  It shows me how to send an email from C#, but how would I pull the data from the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are missing a reference to MS Exchange assembly `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll`

or the using statement `using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;`

For `(3)` you will need to declare and initialise the service object as shown in the linked question.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
```

Note : You can get the assemblies from [Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371)

and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) docs to get started + [Code samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c/view/SamplePack#content)

Comment: I added the .dll you recommend but it did not remove the error?

Comment: Did u put the using statement? `using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;`

Comment: Yes. It underlines the word "Exchange" in the using statement and tells me 'Exchange' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.

Comment: The framework for the project must be set to 4.0 .. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270484/microsoft-exchange-webservices-is-not-working-in-vs2010

Comment: When I click on the property's for my project and look at the Application Tab it shows my Target Framework is .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.  Is that the incorrect framework?

Comment: that got it!  One other question, how would I call the above code from my 'main' method in my console app so it will run?

Comment: Just  move the function GetUnreadMailFromInbox and class MailItem in your Program.cs and call the function in main().. see the C# tutorial http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson05 for more

Comment: When I try to call the Function I get a compile error of An object reference is requred for GetUnreadMailFromInbox.

Comment: That is because main() is static.. u will need to change `public MailItem[] GetUnreadMailFromInbox()` to `public static MailItem[] GetUnreadMailFromInbox()`