# Unable to reference EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Trying to use the `EWS Managed API 2.0` for my `MicroSoft .Net 4.0 (C#, WinForms)` application.

I have downloaded the `EWS Managed API 2.0` and have added a reference to the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll` in my application from `Visual Studio 2010` as required. But I am still unable to include this library with the `using` statement as follows.

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
```

> Error: The type or namespace name 'Exchange' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image: Screenshot of the error enclosed.]
Note: For referencing the API, I have followed the instructions in the following MSDN article: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn528373(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270484/microsoft-exchange-webservices-is-not-working-in-vs2010

Comment: @Sairaj: Thank you very much indeed. That fixed the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target framework of the project needs to be changed from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4" and that will fix this error.

Comment: i am bound to use .net 4 client profile fx.. does it means none of the EWS API version is compatible with .net 4 client profile ?

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan: Yes, looks like the EWS API cannot be accessed from a program using .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.